# Highcharts heatmap not showing data

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm trying to build a highchart heatmap but the I cannot display the data. I'm fairly new to front end and js so maybe I'm missing something.

highchart heatmap

[image: 1]

The data show as label but doesn't display it.

```
\<!doctype html\>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost-canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap'
        },

        boost: {
            useGPUTranslations: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            tickWidth: 1,
            min: 17000,
            max: 25000
        },

        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [-10000, '#3060cf'],
                [0, '#ffffff'],
                [10000, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: -10000,
            max: 10000,
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Stop losses',
            data: {{ csv }},
            nullColor: '#FFFFFF'
        }]

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see the example at the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zx6ukdtn/

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because of a few reasons:

First of all, you have to set `series.colsize` and `series.rowsize` which are 1 by default. In `datetime` axis, you should set them to equal to your time period/unit on a particular axis.

Example code based on your data:

```
  series: [{
    colsize: 36e5, // one hour
    rowsize: 50,
    data: [..]
  }]
```

Secondly, `colorAxis.stops` are defined incorrectly. As API says:

*The stops is an array of tuples, where the first item is a float between **0 and 1** assigning the relative position in the gradient, and the second item is the color.*

Example code:

```
  colorAxis: {
    stops: [
      [0, '#3060cf'], // corresponds to the lowest value (-382.249)
      [0.5, '#ffffff'],
      [1, '#c4463a'] // corresponds to the highest value (0)
    ],
    /* min: - 300,
     max: -10 */ // You can set min and max in the scope of values
  },
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/veo4dybq/

You can read more about `colorAxis.stops` in the following article:
https://highcharts.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/44002324217

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.stops
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.rowsize